# exception after setCompleteRedYellowGreenDef in sumo client c++

Tags: c++, traffic, sumo

I was trying to build up on the example sumo client server in c++ as in the link
http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/TraCI/C%2B%2BTraCIAPI

I wrote a function to build a complete RedYellowGreenDef as in the function below:

```
std::vector<libsumo::TraCILogic> Client::buildCompletetrafficLogics(std::string tlID, int phaseIndex, int increaseVal)
{

 std::vector<libsumo::TraCILogic> logics = trafficlights.getCompleteRedYellowGreenDefinition(tlID);
 for (int i = 0; i < (int)logics.size(); ++i)
 {
 for (int j = 0; j < (int)logics[i].phases.size(); ++j)
 {
 if (logics[i].currentPhaseIndex = phaseIndex)
 {
 logics[i].phases[j].duration = logics[i].phases[j].duration + increaseVal; //increase duration by 5 seconds
 logics[i].phases[j].duration2 = logics[i].phases[j].duration2+ increaseVal;
 }
 }
 }

 return logics;

}
```

I called this function in the main function as follows:

```
//increase duration of phase with index "PhaseIndex" by 5000ms
 std::vector<libsumo::TraCILogic> logics = client.buildCompletetrafficLogics(*tlIt, phaseIndex,5000);
 libsumo::TraCILogic logic = logics[0];
 client.trafficlights.setCompleteRedYellowGreenDefinition(tlID, logic);
```

where tlID is a valid traffic light id, but I faced The following exception when I passed the built logic to setCompleteRedYellowGreenDefinition():

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
>   what():  Storage::writeUnsignedByte(): Invalid value, not in [0, 255]
>   Aborted (core dumped)

Could you help me to find the problem: why I got this exception and how to tackle it?

Comment: "core dumped" so why don't you load the core file into your debugger and investigate? That's what core files are *for* and they are *super useful* in that regard.

Comment: Do you recommend a debugger that work well in sumo src c++?
What editor/IDE you recommend which easily used in sumo?

Comment: I'd just use gdb.

Comment: Which sumo version do you use? Did the client abort or sumo or both? Any other useful messages from the other side of the communication channel?

Comment: I used sumo 0.32 , this exception happened in the client side but it seems based on the exception that this happened during writing the object to the server.